# Difference in MSE between two models

Tags: expected-value, covariance, mean-square-error

Say we have a set of target values $\{y^{(i)}\}_{i=1}^N$ and we have a set of predictions from two different OLS models, i.e., $\{y^{(i)}_A\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{y^{(i)}_B\}_{i=1}^N$.

I am trying to prove that the difference in expected values of the squared error, i.e.,

$$\mathbb{E}[(y_A - y)^2] - \mathbb{E}[(y_B - y)^2]$$

is equivalent to the expected value of the difference in the predictions squared, i.e.,

$$\mathbb{E}[(y_A - y_B)^2]$$

I have tried expanding out the squared differences but I cant see where two start really with this, any help would be appreciated.

Potential solution (not verified):

If $y_A$ and $y_B$ are predictions from an unbiased OLS estimator, then we have:
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E} \left[ (y_{A} - y)^2 \right] &= \sigma^2_{y_{A}} + \mathbb{E} \left[ y_{A} - y \right]^2 \\
    &= \sigma^2_{y_{A}} + 0. \\
    &= \mathbb{E} \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] - \mathbb{E} \left[ y_{A} \right]^2
\end{align}

Substituting this above:

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[(y_A - y)^2] - \mathbb{E}[(y_B - y)^2] &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] - \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A} \right]^2 - \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B}^2 \right] + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B} \right]^2 \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] - \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B}^2 \right] \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B}^2 \right] - 2\mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B}^2 \right] \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] - 2 \left( \sigma^2_{y_{B}} + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B} \right]^2 \right) \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] - \\
    & \quad \quad \quad 2 \left( \rho_{\left( y_{A}, y_{B} \right)} + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A} \right] \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{B} \right] \right) \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right] + \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A}^2 \right) - 2 \mathbb{E}_t \left[ y_{A} \cdot y_{B} \right] \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_t \left[ \left( y_{A} -  y_{B} \right)^2 \right], 
    \label{mc_ols_reform}
\end{align}

where $\rho(\cdot, \cdot)$ is covariance.

Comment: Currently your first display line is zero. Maybe you mistyped a (2) for (1) in the superscript. Anyway, the answer relies on the fact that OLS estimates are unbiased.

Comment: @BenjaminWang would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this is wrong. Where did you get the problem from?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I updated the question with a potential solution that I came up with, what do you think?

Comment: I think you mislabelled The second term (B not A) sometimes. Also how did you get the covariance line?